# Incorporate library when building a static library with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, static-libraries, eclipse-cdt, static-linking

I am creating a static library A which utilizes a 3rd party static library B. I want to provide a single static library which includes my code as well as the required code from library B.

I could extract all the object files from library B, but that does not heop with the problem:

Since my project is a static library project, the *C/C++-Build > Settings > Tool Settings* contains no linker section but an archiver section, thus there is no *Miscellaneous > Other object*s field as it is with executable projects. Do I miss some obvious way or do the Eclipse developers disallow such a field? Can I somehow declare to incorporate the B code?

The only alternative I currently see is to convert the project into a Makefile project.

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra command line options by editing the *Expert Settings:* to set the *Command Line pattern:* to what you want. For example I can add an arbitrary extra .o file by adding it to the end of the line, as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Time for an opinion: I don't think you should be doing that :-) If your library depends on another your application is probably going to need to simply know that and have the extra `-l` for that library too. But this is just an opinion, and I may not understand your use case, in the meantime I hope my answer has helped.